# How do I make glob to return limited number of values?

Tags: php, image, limit, glob

I'm using this script for getting thumbnails from a directory.Here it shows all the images returned by glob().How do I make glob to return limited number of images?Is it possible to limit glob returned values?

```
<?php

$filecount = count(glob("".$usr_alb_path."/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE));

foreach(glob("".$usr_alb_path_thumbs_path."/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE) as $images) 
{ 
  if ($filecount > 1)
  {
     echo "<img class='uploaded_image_live_img_thumbs' alt='".$row["caption"] ."' src=\"".$images."\">";
  }
  else
  {
    //another function
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = 0;
foreach(glob("".$usr_alb_path_thumbs_path."/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE) as $images) {
   if($c++ > 5) break ;
   ...
}
```

or

```
$truncated = array_slice(glob("".$usr_alb_path_thumbs_path."/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE), 0, 5);
foreach($truncated as $images) {
   ...
```

If you have too many files in directory and you want limit result you can use [opendir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) [readdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) or more elegant way - [DirectoryIterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

As `glob()` returns you an array, you can just extract a part of the result via [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

If your directory has too many files / you want to filter them somehow, you have to redesign your persistence layer [and since you are `echo`ing html that way, I suggest to redesign your whole application].